# Find cell position containing search string in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is the lookup table:

```
city            contact person   phone
San Francisco   Peter Foo        123
San Francisco   Steve Foo        321
New York        Max Foo          456
```

I am attempting to find the details for the contact person using VBA:

```
city = Sheets("General User Information").Cells(14, 2).Value
Set cx = Sheets("Cities").Columns(1).Select
Set cy.Find(city)

If Not cy Is Nothing Then
    'here I need to access the contact person and phone but unfortunately
    'fail with various errors (i.e. object required, run time error, etc)
    cyFirst = cy.Address
    Do
        'do something
        Set cy = cx.FindNext(cy)
    Loop Until cy.Address = cyFirst
End If
```

**Question**:
Please show me how I can access the contact person and phone. Please note that one or multiple entries might be found. Many thanks!

Comment: You don't show enough of your code. You don't show any of the variable declaration statements. Assuming cy and cx are declared as Range Objects, you'll need the Set keyword.  Also, why are you `Select`ing cx?

Comment: I must admit that while I have dev background, this is the first time that I use VBA. Thats why I tried to break things into smaller parts hoping to find the error. Updated code a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ will get you in the right track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one of the examples how the search can be implemented

```
Sub test()
    Dim sSearchCriteriaCity$, oCell As Range, i&, x&
    i = 0: x = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' search criteria goes into inputbox
    ' it is better to use the user form for several criterias of searching
    sSearchCriteriaCity = UCase(InputBox("Provide Search Criteria"))

    If sSearchCriteriaCity = "" Then GoTo exitsub 'Exit if criteria was not provided

    For Each oCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & x) 'Column with city
        If UCase(oCell.Value) Like "*" & sSearchCriteriaCity & "*" Then
            oCell.Interior.Color = vbRed ' color cell with red
            i = i + 1
        Else
            oCell.Interior.Color = xlNone ' remove color from cell
        End If
    Next

    If i = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Data matched with search criteria was not found!"
    ElseIf i > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Matched, " & i & " records found!"
    End If

    Exit Sub
exitsub:
        MsgBox "Criteria was not provided!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Offset` feature of the `Range` Object. This allows you to select a cell using a cell/range as the start position.

So in your case

```
' Range.Offset(rows, columns)

Debug.print "City: " & cy.Value2 
' Read the cell one column to the right of cy
Debug.print "Contact Person:" & cy.Offset(0,1).Value2
' Read the cell two columns to the right of cy
Debug.print "Phone: " & cy.Offset(0,2).Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two primary problem areas in your code. The second line should not have `.Select` tacked on the end.

```
Set cx = Sheets("Cities").Columns(1)
```

The third line should be trying to set *cy* to what is found within *cx*.

```
Set cy = cx.Find(city)
```

Put all together as,

```
Dim city As String, cyFirst As String, cx As Range, cy As Range
city = Sheets("General User Information").Cells(14, 2).Value
Set cx = Sheets("Cities").Columns(1)
Set cy = cx.Find(city)

If Not cy Is Nothing Then
    cyFirst = cy.Address
    Do
        With Sheets("General User Information")
            'do something
        'do something
        End With
        Set cy = cx.FindNext(cy)
    Loop Until cy.Address = cyFirst
End If
```